# Regex in sed command does not work properly

Tags: sed, replace, yaml, key-value

I have a yaml file like below.

```
test:
  test_1:
        fact_1: Present
        fact_2: value_1
        tag: tagvalue
  test_2:
        fact_1: NotPresent
        fact_2: null
        tag: null
  test_3:
        fact_1: Present
        fact_2: value_2
        tag: 1.1
        fact_3: 60
  test_4:
        fact_1: Present
        fact_2: value_3
        tag: 5.1
```

I want to update the tag under test_1 section in this yaml file. Note that I don't know the current value of that tag and also I don't know the exact keys and the order of the keys in this yaml file. Also this is a sub section of my full yaml file.

I have tried to use a regular expression to identify this tag value and then update the file with sed command.

```
sed -i 's/\(\stest_1:[\s\S]*?tag\s*:\s*)(\S+)/\1new_tag/' test.yaml
```

When I test the regex separately it identified the test_1 section. But when I execute above sed command it doesn't change anything. Can I know what is the issue here?

Comment: `\s` and `\S` will only work in GNU sed but even there they won't work inside a bracket expression (plus what is the point of matching "space or non-space" vs just `.`?) and `*?` is undefined behavior in any sed or awk or other POSIX tool - I suspect you were trying to use PCRE syntax which no standard POSIX tool understands as they use BREs and EREs, not PCREs.

Comment: I assume when you say `When I test the regex separately it identified the test_1 section.` you mean when you test it in some online tool like regex101 - that only proves the regexp works in that online tool, not that it'll work in any give commandline tool. And even on that site it only proves it produces the expected output for some specific input, not that it works in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is not a `YAML` parser, but instead a text line stream oriented tool.

With Python or go `yq`:

```
$ yq '.test.test_1.tag="new_tag"' file.yaml 
{
  "test": {
    "test_1": {
      "fact_1": "Present",
      "fact_2": "value_1",
      "tag": "new_tag"
    },
    "test_2": {
      "fact_1": "NotPresent",
      "fact_2": null,
      "tag": null
    },
    "test_3": {
      "fact_1": "Present",
      "fact_2": "value_2",
      "tag": 1.1,
      "fact_3": 60
    },
    "test_4": {
      "fact_1": "Present",
      "fact_2": "value_3",
      "tag": 5.1
    }
  }
}
```